# .NET Form close/dispose does not deallocate global objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Edit: Please just take into consideration the sample I provided.  There are no events being called.  The code I provided is all that there is.  I just want to know of global objects in a form must be manually de-allocated.  It would be nice to also know why a form going out of scope doesn't get cleaned up, but that is secondary.

Closing or calling dispose on a Form does not seem to deallocate that form's global objects.  I have a form that will be instantiated multiple times and after opening a number of times I am getting an OutOfMemory exception, even if all the previous forms were closed.  I can get memory to free by making every object I am using disposable, but I thought in general the garbage collection took care of cleaning up objects out of scope.

Here is a simple example of a form with just a multidimensional double array:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace surGroupTool
{
    public partial class TestForm : Form
    {
        double[,] testArray;

        public TestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            testArray = new double[5000, 5000];
        }

    }
}
```

When I create the form in an infinite loop it quickly runs out of memory, even if I dispose and set it to null.

```
while (true)
{
    TestForm testForm = new TestForm();

    testForm.Dispose();
    testForm = null;
}
```

Must every object be manually disposed for a closed/disposed form?

[image]

Comment: I've put this code in a simple console app, took out the InitializeComponent() method on the constructor, and I don't get any memory usage problems. What other objects is on the form, and you can force the garbage collector to freeup memory after a dispose with `GC.Collect();`

Comment: This happens even if each form is created by a user clicking a button...with minutes between forms being created.

Comment: `Dispose()` does not reclaim memory used by an object.   It only releases unmanaged resources such as file handles.

Comment: Sounds like the form reference is still being kept alive by winforms.

Comment: Have you tried to find a memory leak in your app? The `TestForm` objects might e.g. get some events subscriptions that prevent the objects from being processed by the GC. Search for memory leaks using a memory profiler.

Comment: The `Dispose` method frees _unmanaged_ resources such as _handles_. It doesn't free _memory_!

Comment: Alexander - So every object used in a form must be manually de-allocated?

Comment: dymanoid - The test code I provided has no events and has the same issue

Comment: Well, then create a loop with, say, 5 iterations and run a memory profiler to check whether the instances were garbage collected. If not, you have a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: Works fine for me, memory is stable.

Comment: dymanoid - I know I have a memory leak, I am trying to understand why.  I thought when a form went out of scope that GC would clean up it's objects.  Don't worry about my other form, I want to know why the example I gave is holding on to memory.

Comment: where is your "while (true)" code belongs to? do you have stack trace?

Comment: The while (true) is in the Form_Load of another form.

Comment: There's a difference in disposing and releasing memory and dispose doesn't have anything to do with managed types (unless you want to manage them in a dispose .... Anyway ).  This doesn't look lime a simple answer l, recommend reading about garbage collection first.  That'll help you understand it.

Comment: @warpjedi - The GC doesn't ever call `.Dispose()` on `IDisposable` objects. Never. However, it may call a finalizer and a finalizer may call `.Dispose()`. Unless you inspect the source code you never know if it might.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I was unable to reproduce the issue with the given source code. This screenshot is from about 20 seconds. But I left it running while getting coffee and it was still fine. It was looping the memory pattern as shown above.

One thing I noticed is that it takes some time before the GC frees up memory. The GC only runs when your starting to get low on memory or when manually calling it with `GC.Collect();`. At that point a background process will start that does the actual cleaning. This garbage collection thread does not fully interrupt your programs main thread (according to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) > background workstation garbage collection). So this means that it is possible to keep allocating memory even when the GC is running. At that point it is a race who's first. You in allocating enough memory to get out of bounds. or your GC with its cleanup.

> Must every object be manually disposed for a closed/disposed form?

No, generally global resources do not have to be disposed. The GC will clean them up if nothing is referencing them. However if a global resources is an unmanaged resources (like a `stream` or a `bitmap`) you need to dispose it before it can be cleaned, this is the same for local unmanaged resource.

from the comments:

> This happens even if each form is created by a user clicking a button...with minutes between forms being created.

I'm going to assume that this is in your real application and not with the form provided as a test sample. You are most likely leaving a reference to that form (for example via a dialog result, or open undamaged resource). If it is with the given form I cannot explain it and you might need to check if you haven't overwritten the GC settings to something very exotic, or disabled it all together.

Comment: I created a new project and was not able to reproduce my issue with my sample.  I moved the test code in my main app from the form load to the form constructor and it did not have an issue.  My main app is using a lot of custom and 3rd party controls, perhaps one of them is causing the problem.

Comment: @warpjedi You didn't document your question regarding custom controls.  Any of those controls do custom drawing?  Etc.

Comment: @warpjedi fair change, specially if you use something with pictures or the like in it. A lot of people forget to dispose those in controls

Comment: @NickOtten - The GC doesn't ever call `.Dispose()` on `IDisposable` objects. Never. However, it may call a finalizer and a finalizer may call `.Dispose()`. Unless you inspect the source code you never know if it might.